# How can I ask for the raise that I feel I deserve?

Tags: management, raise

So when I started at this company, I had no experience in this industry. That being said, I was hired in at a pretty good rate as a level 1 Engineer. I knew my skills would latch on to the work being done and I would take off. And that is exactly what happened. Within 3 months I got a $5/hr raise to Level 2 (yes i know its a big raise). So I continue busting it for another calendar year. I choose to step into a leadership role as a QA, and get take the pay raise of $7 more an hour (a HUGE increase). I felt very appreciated by management and continued busting it since then.

Another calendar year went by, and I decided to have a polite conversation about the next step. There is 1 more raise offered, its $3 more an hour up to $35/hr to become a Sr. QA that is on par with the Sr. Engineer in pay. I know it exists, several people I have come to know closely have it. Now my manager tells me I will never get that raise. I asked why and was told that it was just an experience thing. I only had the 2 years and they came in with near 10. Honestly to me I was convinced by it and thanked my boss and went back to work. I KNOW Im compensated well, I KNOW I'm coming across as not grateful by asking, but i felt i needed to.

Now lets jump ahead a couple more months. I had a little bit of downtime and started pulling up numbers from when I was production vs being a QA. I calculate out the amount of money I have made for the company (i know the production pay rates per mile). And as an engineer, NOT QA i made the company tons of money and was put in what were considered the untouchable, hairiest projects we had to work on. As a QA i have been involved with twice as much money, but have a team of 10 engineers. So I alone could produce as much as 5 people on my team that is in the top 3 of production out of the teams in office.

Doing a little more digging i pulled up the production done by other engineers with the higher paygrade. And even though I had not done production for over a calendar year, I STILL made more money than them by a large margin. I am still in the top 15 in production of 120 people despite not having done any in over a year. So having made that much money, on top of having a top tier team as a QA, AND being the Go-To team for new or difficult jobs, I have provided tremendous value to this company.

**So with all that in mind, how can I approach management about asking for that next and last step?** I feel like I can make the case with my numbers, but I don't know how to handle it in a way that doesn't seem ungrateful. I feel like I'm being one of *those* people since I technically haven't put in the years of work.

Comment: Can you clarify the nature of the raise you're seeking? It sounds like you started as Engineer 1, were promoted to Engineer 2 and received a raise, promoted again to QA and received a raise. There is one more raise you're seeking, am I correct to understand that it is tied to another promotion? Or are you comparing your pay rate to others with 10 years experience?

Comment: The next step is considered a Sr. QA in relation to the Sr. Engineer that I could have been on track for had I stayed in production. Will clarify in post.

Comment: What are the responsibilities of the Sr. QA position? Do you feel you are qualified to assume them?

Comment: Also, you can look at the "related" list to the right for more potential duplicates.

Comment: One other question, in your second paragraph, you indicated that another year went by and you asked your manager about the raise associated with being promoted to Senior QA. Did you receive any sort of raise at whatever the company's standard interval is (or does the company only grant raises with promotions)?

Comment: I lied, one more question, do you receive bonuses?

Comment: Company only gives raises as promotions. Yes we get a yearly bonus, it is not on par with other company's bonuses but i wont complain about any extra money.

Comment: It seems like the question @dwizum linked is similar enough that I can consult that for advice. Although not exactly the same, I think maybe close enough

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not state that you 'deserve' a raise.  This will make you sound like a whiner - which you are not.

Instead, state your case in business terms.  You've already started this process.  I would also do some market research for your area for similar positions with other employers.  You need to know what you're up against.

Now when having a discussion with management share the numbers of money made and/or saved.  Gratitude should have nothing to do with the discussion.  You are either paid according to your contribution to the bottom line of the business or your are not.

If (as your manager states) you will never get to the next level because of lack of experience then have two options - stay where you're at and not get paid for the value you bring to the business (bottom line plus your market research) -or- leave for a different employer that will fairly compensate you for the value you bring to the company.

Comment: Right, I never intended to tell them to their face that I deserve the raise. It's just an internal feeling to myself that I deserve it and can justify it